# How to get the value of a url parameter?

Tags: java, jax-rs

Im using Jax-rs and Im trying to find a way to access the last parameter of a url.

For example: http://localhost:8080/myproject/api/movie?userid=test

I want to get the value test out of my request.

Comment: Given that you showed no actual code, I will direct you to [this good MKyong tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jax-rs-queryparam-example/), which shows how to access query parameters in Jax-RS.

Comment: thanks this helped me alot! `System.out.println(requestContext.getUriInfo().getQueryParameters().getFirst("userid"));` this did the job for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@QueryParam`
For your URL

```
 http://localhost:8080/myproject/api/movie?userid=test

@QueryParam("userid") int userid;
```

Now you can use the value

```
System.out.println(userid);
```